# More elegant way to express a CSS selector

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors

Is there a more elegant way to write the following CSS selector?

```
input:not([type="image"]):not([type="submit"])
```

I want to match all HTML `input` elements that are not of type `image` or of type `submit`.

Target browser is *only* Firefox, so Mozilla CSS extensions are fine.

Comment: Nothing... just isn't very elegant due to the repetition of `:not([type="..."])`, but perhaps that's the best way to write it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way to write the following CSS selector?

No, there isn't. Firefox 3 previously allowed `:not()` to contain any number of selectors which would have allowed you to write

```
input:not([type="image"], [type="submit"])
```

but that was technically a bug as the syntax wasn't in any standard at the time, and it no longer works in any major release since. It's now in [Selectors 4](http://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation), though, so hopefully it'll return soon.

Selectors 4 also contains `:matches()`, which is implemented in Firefox as `:-moz-any()`, however you can't use that as it doesn't accept negations (seeing as `:not()` will have the same expanded syntax anyway, it doesn't make sense to have each allow the other, but then you wonder why they didn't implement a `:-moz-not()` to go with it).

Comment: Yes, `:-moz-not()` would be useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
input:not([type="image"], [type="submit"])
```

but your selector match is better.

Comment: Isn't that something entirely different?  What does that match?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: It's the same in principle. It matches input elements that do not satisfy any of the conditions given. Only caveat is that it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  But it's not valid right now in Firefox.  I gave it a try, but no dice.